# PhpStorm - will not stop indexing program files

Tags: indexing, phpstorm

weird issue here with PHP storm - it goes through indexing all of my project files fine but when it is at like 99.999% it begins to index PhpStorm plugin files located in my `Program Files/Jetbrains/PhpStorm` folder.

There is no way I can find for me to exclude this folder from indexing. The indexing never stops and I can't work.

Any solutions? I've already invalidated cache several times.

Using PhpStorm 2017 v3.4 on Windows 10 Pro

File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP tab:
[image]

Comment: Please show screenshot of your `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP` -- Includes tab.

Comment: I posted above!

Comment: I meant the whole list... Anyway -- please check if you have `.` (dot) entry there -- usually that's what is causing it.

Comment: It would literally just be "."? Don't see that there!

Comment: Yes, just dot. That's the only possible reason that comes into my mind right now... If you do not have such entry -- try deleting `.idea` subfolder (while project is closed of course) and re-create project from scratch (use "Open" and point to the project root folder). Maybe it's something with the project settings. Otherwise -- check `idea.log` for possible hints (`Help | Show Log in XXX`)

Comment: Other than that -- try "File | Invalidate Caches" and restart IDE -- might help. But the whole issue is why it check plugins folder of IDE installation... Somehow/somewhere that path (or just "." dot) is used ... Hopefully idea.log can help here.

Comment: Is Z - a network drive? That might cause this. Try to switch to local drive & check again